# Error in enc2utf8(x) : argumemt is not a character vector

Tags: r, text-mining

`Error in enc2utf8(x) : argumemt is not a character vector` is the error I get when I try to run the code below in R 3.1.2 . can anyone please help me understand if I am missing something here ?

OS used is Windows

```
#Text Cleaning: tm Code
  clean<-function(text){
  library(NLP)
  library(tm)
  sample<- Corpus(VectorSource(text),readerControl=list(language="english"))
  sample<- tm_map(sample, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "bytes"))
  sample<-tm_map(sample,removePunctuation)
  sample <- tm_map(sample, stripWhitespace)
  sample<-tm_map(sample,removeNumbers)
  sample<-tm_map(sample,removeWords,stopwords('smart'))
  sample <- tm_map(sample, stripWhitespace)
  sample <- tm_map(sample, stripWhitespace)
  dtm <- DocumentTermt(sample[1:3])Matrix(sample)
  return(list(sample,dtm))
  }
 fileName <- 'input.txt'
 test = readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
 clean (test)
```

Comment: Maybe `sample<- tm_map(sample, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "bytes")))` (assuming you're sure this step is necessary).

Comment: thank for pointing that it . I Tried it . Still no work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to refer to the `content` of the corpus, i.e., the character vector in `sample$content`:

```
tm_map(sample, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x$content), sub = "bytes"))
```

Here, I replaced `enc2utf8(x)` with `enc2utf8(x$content)`.

Answer (score 0):

Small change to your code into below 2 line may solve your problem

```
sample<- VCorpus(VectorSource(text),readerControl=list(language="english"))
sample<- tm_map(sample, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "bytes")))
```